# Compile time recursive using C++ template functions

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

Is the following code is compile time recursive? I would like to know how to confirm this i.e any debugger,profiler etc to understand template programs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
std::vector<std::thread> vecc;

void thread_fn(){
    std::cout<<"Thread function"<<"\n"; 
}

template <int n>
void create_thread(){
    create_thread<n-1>();
    vecc.push_back(std::thread(thread_fn));
}
template<>
void create_thread<0>(){
    vecc.push_back(std::thread(thread_fn));
}

int main()
{
    create_thread<10>();
    for(auto &a: vecc){
        a.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Despite what you're asking, I don't think threads can be spawned at compile time.

Comment: The generated code for `create_thread<10>()` has the same meaning as 10 lines of `vecc.push_back(std::thread(thread_fn))`, if that's what you are asking

Comment: Related (but more broad) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325910/debugging-template-instantiations

Comment: The templates are recursive and templates are instantiated at compile-time, so...

Comment: I wanted to know if the function create_thread will be called recursively in run-time resulting in growth of stack or compiler will generate the code for create_thread 10 times. The answer below clarifies that.

Comment: @SivaramL the answer would be kindof "*both*"... it's not real recursion, but its still 10 nested function calls with growing stack.

Comment: @grek40 I could not understand it fully, can you please explain?

Comment: @Sivaram well the compiler generates the code for `create_thread` 10 times, but still this code will contain a nested function call in 9 out of 10 times. The stack grows whenever a nested function is called, not only on recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For gcc you can use `-fdump-tree-original` option:

```
g++ -fdump-tree-original -Wall -pthread 111.cpp
```

Now you can see how `create_thread` template is getting instantiated in generated dump:

```
$ grep create_thread 111.cpp.003t.original
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 0] (null)
  create_thread<10> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 10] (null)
  create_thread<9> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 9] (null)
  create_thread<8> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 8] (null)
  create_thread<7> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 7] (null)
  create_thread<6> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 6] (null)
  create_thread<5> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 5] (null)
  create_thread<4> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 4] (null)
  create_thread<3> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 3] (null)
  create_thread<2> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 2] (null)
  create_thread<1> () >>>>>;
;; Function void create_thread() [with int n = 1] (null)
  create_thread<0> () >>>>>;
```